# Windows Failover Cluster : Can it fallback to secondary node on certain window service failure

Tags: windows, windows-cluster

We have 2 nodes in windows cluster , each box has 12 Windows Services running which are specific to a product. Our requirement is if any of these services stops working or fail to start at any time on active node, then the cluster should fallback to secondary node , is this possible ? Is there any such feature in windows clustering?

Answer (score 5):

Take something like Starwinds to replicate the data between the servers. I'm not sure can it handle your specific services, but you can always ask their engineers. https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san#VSAN-FREE

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question. Just add each service as a `Service` role to the cluster and point your product to the service on the cluster.

Comment: It needs IP address for each service Role , why it can't take cluster ip for Service role ?